# Convert all records in postgres to Titlecase, first letter uppercase

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table in PostgreSQL called keywords with a simple text field called name. I want to convert all names of keywords in first letter uppercase. Is there a way to do it from psql console?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is an `initcap()` function, if you're meaning to uppercase the first letter of each keyword and to lowercase the following characters:

```
update foo
set bar = initcap(bar)
```

Else combine `substring()` and `upper()`:

```
update foo
set bar = upper(substring(bar from 1 for 1)) ||
          substring(bar from 2 for length(bar))
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: initcap doesn't work fine with non-english characters e.g. initcap(R. López Viña Tondonia Rioja White Viña) gives output as "R. LóPez ViñA Tondonia Rioja White ViñA". The correct output is "R. López Viña Tondonia Rioja White Viña"

Comment: @PradeepKumarMishra, it seems to work now. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302827/915529

Comment: You can write substring conversion little bit shorter
upper(substring(bar for 1)) || substring(bar from 2)

Answer (score 12):

```
select initcap('r. lópez viña tondonia Rioja White Viña');
```

This does give the correct answer (R. López Viña Tondonia Rioja White Viña) in our version of Postgres (9.0.7).

Answer (score 3):

@denis, Gave the Right Answer!

But in my case I use PgAdmin3 , so after selecting the database there is SQL query Options , So there we can directly add the above query in it.

I had a table called subcategory_subcategory(name of table) in that i wanted to change a column values whose name was Item_name(name of column ) , *so my query was like this*

```
update subcategory_subcategory
set Item_name = initcap(Item_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

The initcap function capitalizes letters after special characters (dashes, apostrophes, etc). I only want to capitalize after a space.

Similar to Denis' answer, this function will convert the first letter of every word (separated by a space)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION titlecase(instr varchar) RETURNS varchar AS $$
DECLARE
  strarray varchar[] := string_to_array(inStr, ' ');
  outstrarray varchar[];
  word varchar;
BEGIN
  FOREACH word IN ARRAY strarray
  LOOP
    outstrarray := array_append(outstrarray, (upper(left(word,1))::varchar || 
lower(right(word,-1))::varchar)::varchar);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN array_to_string(outstrarray,' ','');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```