# How to converts all the first letter to upper case in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

Below given is my sample select

```
 select thename from tblname

    thename 
   -------------
   cash in hands
   round offs
   bank charges
```

So,How to *convert all first letter to upper case* in the above *select* ?

```
  select some_postgres_function from tblname

     thename 
   -------------
   Cash In Hands
   Round Offs
   Bank Charges
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert all records in postgres to have first letter uppercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176057/convert-all-records-in-postgres-to-have-first-letter-uppercase)

Comment: @dude I dint get this before i was in a hurry that's why i directly post this question before searching

Comment: "*why i directly post this question before searching*" - really? So you let other people do the searching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some_postgres_function is [initcap](http://coderlearner.com/PostgreSQL_INITCAP)

```
 select initcap(thename) from tblname
```

[String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: Here is the link to the official manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i know it but [this](http://coderlearner.com/Category:PostgreSQL) seems easier to read

Comment: @dude thanks for the answer and the alternative PostgreSQL reference

Answer (score 0):

if you have a small subset, for example like you have in the example ( 3)

you can take the content as a string and create an array with its content with separated by " " and capitalize each element of array

Comment: is that necessary ??  just have a look on [PostgreSQL INITCAP](http://coderlearner.com/PostgreSQL_INITCAP)

Comment: This answer would be better if you provided the code to illustrate what you're describing.