# Create table using sqlalchemy core with data using title case

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Using **sqlalchemy core** only I wish to define the table such that every time data is saved in the table, data is converted to title case.**How can this be done at table definition level**? The way table is being defined now is:

```
roles = Table("roles", metadata,
              Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column("name", String, unique=True, default=mycase, onupdate=mycase))
```

In the above, I always wish to save the data as 'Project Manager' even when the user enters the data as 'project maNager' or 'project Manager' etc. This will avoid efforts of formatting in the code before saving the data. Database used is postgresql 9.4.

I have used this functionality of Sqlalchemy core 1.2 mentioned here: 
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html

```
# a function which counts upwards
i = 0
def mydefault():
    global i
    i += 1
    return i

t = Table("mytable", meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, default=mydefault),
)
```

But doesn't seem to work with sqlalchemy core 1.0.8:

```
def mycase(context):
    return context.title()

roles = Table("roles", metadata,
                  Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                  Column("name", String, unique=True, default=mycase, onupdate=mycase))
```

Comment: Well, what's the question here?

Comment: May be you just *Title Case* user input before writing to database as `'project manager'.title()` , is that too much efforts?

Comment: I would like to keep it at db level so that this statement can be avoided during add  and edit and can be done for all the other tables in the db

Comment: Plus, what DB driver are you using with SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: psycopg2 db driver

Comment: Write a trigger in the DB, follow instructions on title casing stuff in Postgres: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176057/convert-all-records-in-postgres-to-titlecase-first-letter-uppercase