# How can I switch case for each letter in a string with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to convert this into this using PostgreSQL

```
dxItw9a4 --> DXiTW9A4
```

Is there any function or way that is already set?

Comment: is it always the same string length?  See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Be inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49846732/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only dealing with the characters A-Z, you can use the [translate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) function in postgres to convert cases.

```
select TRANSLATE(
    'dxItw9a4', -- original text
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', -characters to change
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' -- replacement characters.
)
```

You can simplify it slightly be using the upper/lower functions.

```
select TRANSLATE(
    'dxItw9a4',  -- original text
    upper('dxItw9a4')||lower('dxItw9a4'), --characters to search for
    lower('dxItw9a4')||upper('dxItw9a4') -- replacement characters
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works by splitting the string into a resultset of charaters using `regexp_split_to_table()`, then converts them to the opposite case and joins them again using aggregate function `string_agg()`:

```
select 
    string_agg(case when c ~ '[a-z]' then upper(c) else lower(c) end, '') res
from (
    select * from regexp_split_to_table('dxItw9a4', '') as chars(c)
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=24e48e9a09c23c331f34aa3360985c2a)**:

```
| res      |
| :------- |
| DXiTW9A4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods supported by PostreSQL:

```
UPPER(string_expression)
```

Example:

```
SELECT
   CONCAT (
      UPPER (first_name),
      UPPER (last_name)
   ) as full_name
FROM
   staff;
```

Reference: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-letter-case-functions/

Comment: Needs an invert for cases not upper and PostgreSql does not contain one.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the OP is looking for a SQL version of the `swapcase()` function found in many client-side languages. A few thoughts:

1. Use `swapcase()` on the client side. I'd do that.
2. Figure out a clever regex? I'm not that clever.
3. Roll something by hand.

I figured I'd give #3 a try, and wrote some code. The kindest thing I can say about this function is that it works...but I doubt it's much good. I'm trying to beef up my PL/pgSQL skills, so any comments on improving the code welcomed. It's so much easier to write a lot of things in most other languages...but there are plenty of cases where pushing the logic onto the server is beneficial, I figure it's worth putting in some effort to get comfortable in PL/pgSQL. But, again, I'd use `swapcase()`, or  a hand-rolled equivalent, on the client side, I'd expect.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION swapcase(in_text text) RETURNS text as
$BODY$
DECLARE
    out_text text;
    test_char text;
    ascii_code smallint;
    characters_arr_text  text[];
begin

   out_text  :='';
   test_char := '';
   select into characters_arr_text regexp_split_to_array(in_text,'');

    FOREACH test_char IN array characters_arr_text LOOP

        ascii_code := ascii(test_char);

        IF (ascii_code BETWEEN 65 and 90) THEN 
            out_text := out_text || LOWER(test_char);

        ELSIF (ascii_code BETWEEN 97 and 122) THEN 
            out_text := out_text || UPPER(test_char);

         ELSE
          out_text := out_text || test_char;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    RETURN out_text;

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Here's a call:

```
select swapcase('dxItw9a4'); --  DXiTW9A4
```

And a longer call to show that it works:

```
select 'dxItw9a4' as input,
        swapcase('dxItw9a4') as output,
        'DXiTW9A4' as expected_output,
        swapcase('dxItw9a4') = 'DXiTW9A4' as pass;
```

## Better

Here's a `swapcase()` function that uses GMB's code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION swapcase(in_text text) RETURNS text as
$BODY$

    select string_agg(
                case when character ~ '[a-z]' then 
                    upper(character) 
                else 
                    lower(character)
                 end, '') as result_text

    from (select * 
            from regexp_split_to_table(in_text, '') as character) as subquery

$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```